# Non-integer powers of complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

When introducing branch points and branch cuts I had a lecture on non-integer powers of complex number. To explore it I google it and get a paper where it was explained using polar representation of complex number. Here is the snippet,

> [image: question]

I didn't understand how they get the set of values and why this set of values is independent of the numerator $P$? It will be great help if anyone explain it.

Comment: In order to enumerate the set of possible values, and ensuring no common divsor, in the set, $P$ is running from $1, 2, 3, \ldots, Q-2, Q-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantities in the curly brackets are called the roots of unity. In the complex plane,
they sit at $Q$ evenly-spaced points on the unit circle, with $1$ as one of the values.